# how to write testcase of Appium automation testing for android and where to write? and how to execute the test case?

Tags: android, testcase, appium

I searched in google and see java code like:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "Android");
capabilities.setCapability("device", "Android");
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.2");
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Windows");
capabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\\Android Apps\\Calculator.apk");      
//This is path of your application
capabilities.setCapability("app-package", "com.calculator");                   
 // This is package name of your app
capabilities.setCapability("app-activity", "MainActivity");                          
// This Launcher activity of your app
RemoteWebDriver remoteWebDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

But I am not understanding where to write the code and after that how to write the test case and execute. I will thankful if guide me step by step.

Comment: thank you for editing @Paresh. could you please tell me How to make paragraph and add code when as you edited my question ?

Answer (score 0):

I am also on the same level as you are. I am on a windows platform. First make sure that appium app is running. 
Make a java project and paste the code above inside a class of this project. It is pretty straight forward. Run the project and thats it!

Make sure that your URL in your code is pointing on the same url that you defined in you appium app. Also that (in this case) Calculator.apk is available on the path you define since appium needs the apk to run the test.

Cheers!

Comment: thank your reply @Metalsok. I am following your guide line and getting the following error when running the java application i am getting the  error: **Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not make strings from apk) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)**   why this error?

Comment: i have solved it by putting the "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin" this in the path of Environment variable.

Comment: now please guide me how write the testcase and how to execute ?